# Copy all methods from one class to another on the fly

Tags: ruby

I have two classes and I want to copy all of the methods from one class to another.  Some methods will have no arguments, some will have arguments, and some will have hashes as arguments.  And I never know in advance which ones will.  So I created this code, until I figured out that it didn't take into account arguments.  Is there any way to get a list of methods from a Class, and then clone them exactly to another class?

```
def partial(cls)
  cls.instance_methods(false).each do |method_name|
    define_method(method_name) do
      cls.new.method(method_name.to_sym).call
    end
  end
end
```

The methods are created on the fly using define_method in the first class, so I can't just use an include.  The code above has cls being passed in, then it finds all of the instance methods that are actually written in that Class, not ones it inherits, and then creates a new method with the same name.  When that method is called, it actually calls the other Class with its method of the same name.  This works wonderfully, unless I have args.  I had condition check to see if it had arguments, and then had it call a method with arguments, but it did not handle hashes very well.  It made the hash as an array for an argument, which is not what I wanted.

I was wondering if there was a simple way to literally say "Hey you know this method, whatever it is, literally make the same thing for this other Class."

Comment: I'm confused about what you want to do.  You are talking about instance methods, but then you say 'calls the other Class with its method of the same name`.  That can't work unless you are keeping track of an insance of the other class.

Answer (score 2):

you could also try [DelegateClass](http://www.ruby-doc.org/docs/ProgrammingRuby/html/lib_patterns.html):

```
class NamedArray < DelegateClass(Array)
  def initialize n
    @name = n
    super(Array.new)
  end
  def sayName
    "My name is #{@name}"
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

If all the methods are identical, why not just define them in a common module which you include in both classes?  You mention not using include because the methods are dynamically defined, but that doesn't mean they won't be found when you mixin the module:

```
module Foo
  def self.make_an_example_method(name)
    define_method(name) do |*args|
      puts "I am #{name} called with (#{args.inspect})"
    end
  end
end

class A
  include Foo
end

class B
  include Foo
end

Foo.make_an_example_method(:example)
Foo.make_an_example_method(:dynamic)

A.new.example         # => I am example called with ([])
B.new.dynamic(1,2,3)  # => I am dynamic called with ([1, 2, 3])
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try SimpleDelegator: http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/delegate/rdoc/SimpleDelegator.html